# get previous url in magento as a string

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I try to obtain last/previous URL and I can't get like an URL.

Here is my code:

```
lastUrl =  Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

And I try extract the URL from this array, but it give me this error:

> Cannot use object of type Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http as array

using: `var_dump($lastUrl['value'])`

Or `null` if I try `$lastUrl->value`

How I can extract the URL as a string? I always have trouble with this arrays.

Comment: Is working if i use $laastUrlString = $lastUrl->getHeaders()[2]['value'];

Answer (score 3):

You can use below code for referer URL get and redirect to that URL

```
$url = Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer() ? Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer()  : Mage::getUrl();
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
```

Comment: yes, i know that, but i need the url as a string, because i wanna modify the previous url. is work if i use $laastUrlString = $lastUrl->getHeaders()[2]['value'];

Comment: this Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer() it give me large array

Comment: You can get URL from array. if not send me array file.

Comment: `$response = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse();
$response->setRedirect($url);` you can use this code instead that.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your controller:

```
$lastUrl = $this->_getRefererUrl();
echo $lastUrl; exit;
```